# webSecurityConfig permitAll doesnt work for method annotations

Tags: java, spring, security

i cannot bypass spring security @PreAuthorize("hasRole('ROLE_ROLE')")
with WebSecurityConfig, i tried e.g. antMatchers("/**").permitAll 
How is it possible to overcome this?

Comment: Nor will you ever be able to. It isn't either or the other they are complementary.

Comment: @M.Deinum so how can I make all methods available from specific IP? or add roles to specific ip?

Comment: Write the proper expression(s). `hasIpAddress` is something you can use and you can also extend the language with your own set of expression. So something like `@PreAuthorize("hasRole('ROLE_ROLE') || (hasIpAddress('ip-address-here') && hasPermission('my-permission))") no it will work if you have the `ROLE_ROLE` or if you have a specific ipaddress together with a specific role.

Comment: But i want  use this generic for all annotations, whats the best approach?